# Changing default colour of segmented bar in Xcode 5.0 for iOS7?

Tags: colors, ios7, xcode5, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm a beginner.. could use your help!

Need to change the default colour of a segmented control - the tint merely 'overlays' the desired colour which only appears in the app once the segmented control has been tapped.

How do I go about having my desired colour when the app loads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Interface Builder to create your UI, you can set the tint of the segmented control in the Attributes Inspector:

[image: Screenshot showing tint setting in Interface Builder's Attributes inspector]

This works both for bar segmented controls and plain segmented controls, as can be seen in this screenshot from the simulator:

[image: Screenshot showing app with two tinted segmented controls]

If you're setting the segmented control's tint colour in code, it should work if you do it in your view controller's viewDidLoad method, like this:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.barSegmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    self.plainSegmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the result:

[image: Screenshot showing app with two segmented controls tinted in viewDidLoad]

Comment: If this worked for you, would you mind accepting it as the answer to your question?

Comment: No worries Greg, sorry about that.